# How to get java scanner class to read a file as a argument from cmd

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've got from code for java which I want to use the scanner class to output the contents of the file token by token from a file that was as an argument from the command line but it doesn't seem to work for me for some reason.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class HashTable {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    File inputfile = new File(args[0]);

    try {

        Scanner sr = new Scanner(inputfile);

        while (sr.hasNextLine()) {
        int i = sr.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
        }
        sr.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: What is the behavior? Is it throwing any exception or printing nothing at all?

Comment: It's printing the first item but after that it says exception in thread main java.MisMatchException, the file has a mixture of numbers and letters

Comment: share the complete error as well as the input file

Comment: Don't worry I was messing around with it and fixed it, I got rid of the 'while (sr.hasNextLine())' bit and it's working fine now. Thank you to though for taking the time to try and help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

> int i = sr.nextInt();

by

> String i = sr.next();

MisMatchException is caused by token out of range (to be converted into integer)

Comment: Thanks I didn't see your comment but I did that anyway and it works now. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    final String input = "1 two 3 four five 6 7";
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
    while ( scanner.hasNext() )
    {
        if ( scanner.hasNextInt() )
        {
            System.out.println( "int: " + scanner.nextInt() );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ( "String: " + scanner.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

int i = sr.nextInt();
System.out.println(i);

use

System.out.println(sr.nextLine());